# meteor: display array data as table gives duplicate value on adding new column

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, spacebars

I'm trying to display this array data...

```
var data = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ]
];
```

in a table in my meteor app:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        {{#each data}}
            <tr>
                {{#each this}}
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{this}}"></td>

                {{/each}}
                <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

There should always be an empty `input` at the end of each row for adding new colomns.

If an input gets changed, the data will be stored to the collection:

```
'change input': function(event) {
    var data = [],
        tr   = [];

    $('tbody tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            tr.push($(this).val());
        });
        data.push(tr);
    });

    Table.update(
        { _id: id },
        { $set: 
            {
                data: data 
            }
        }
    );

},
```

But if I do an input on the last input, the new field is added to the array, but the value gets also displayed for the new last input field - so there is a duplicate shown. I don't understand why, as in the template markup the last field is always empty, as it doesn't get any value and it is outside of the `each`-loop.

It seems as the last input array keeps the value, which the user typed and the new data array is used for building the template.

Comment: (1) According to your provided code, the array `tr` is never emptied after pushing into array `data`, so, the number of input fields should increase exponentially with each `change` event. (2) Due to the way, the jQuery script has been devised, every `change` event will increase the number of fields by 1 at least, whether new data has been entered or not. (3) The reason for the **duplication** seems to be due to the way Meteor re-renders templates. Meteor probably _updates_ the DOM wherever necessary, instead of simply deleting and regenerating it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the **duplication** seems to be due to the way Meteor re-renders templates. Meteor probably *updates* the DOM wherever necessary, instead of simply deleting and regenerating it from scratch.

If you check your database, you will see that the duplicate data is only in the browser/front-end and not updated on the backend MongoDB database.

You can correct it by simply emptying the input element once you've handled the `change` event:

```
    'change input': function(event) {
        var data = [],
            tr = [];

        $('tbody tr').each(function() {
            $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {

                tr.push($(this).val());

            });
            data.push(tr);

            // Emptying the tr array after pushing into data array
            tr = [];
        });

        Table.update({ _id: id }, {
            $set: {
                data: data
            }
        });

        // Emptying the value of the input element which triggered the event
        event.currentTarget.value = "";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor doesn't re-render the enter template when a template data is changed. It just updates the template and elements which are directly affected by the change in data and rest html remains same. So in your case, you need to clear the last input field each time the insertion is done. I updated your code to show the correct result. -

```
<template name="testgrid">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        {{#each data}}
            <tr>
                {{#each this}}
                    <td><input type="text" value="{{this}}"></td>
                {{/each}}
                <td><input type="text" value="" class="newValue"></td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

var dataTable = [
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ],
    [ 'field 1', 'field 2', 'field 3' ]
];

var Table = new Mongo.Collection(null);
Table.insert({
    data: dataTable
});

Template.testgrid.rendered = function() {
}

Template.testgrid.helpers({
   data : function () {
       return Table.findOne({}).data;
   }
});

Template.testgrid.events({
    'change input': function(event) {
        var tempData = [],
            tr   = [];

        $('tbody tr').each(function() {
            tr = [];
            $(this).find('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
                var tempValue = $(this).val();
                if(tempValue)
                    tr.push(tempValue);
            });
            tempData.push(tr);
        });

        $('.newValue').val("");
        var table = Table.findOne({});
        Table.update(table, {$set: {data: tempData}});
    }
});
```